# What is the recommended way for switching between multiple browser configs with protractor

Tags: protractor

I have a suite of protractor tests I'm currently running. I have a config.js that is only setup to run Chrome with 'capabilities'.  See below.

```
  capabilities: {
  }
    browserName: 'chrome'
  }
```

I have the following execution scenarios requirements:

1. Execute tests in Chrome only
2. Execute tests in Firefox only
3. Execute with Chrome/Firefox/IE

I'd like to be able to override (via command args) my current config.js by using something like the following:

1. *protractor config.js* (already setup for Chrome only in config)
2. *protractor config.js
   --browser=firefox* (this obviously works 'out of
       box')
3. *protractor config.js --browsers=chrome,firefox,ie* (not
   available to my knowledge)

Option #3 isn't a real command (but I'd like it to be)

**Question**: Is there a command I can use to override the single capability to "multiCapabilities" or do you recommend using 2 config files? One for a single browsers and one for multi-browsers?

**Note**: I'd like to have only 1 config.js because I have all my suites defined in the config.js and don't really want multiples anyhow.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **multiCapabilities**

```
multiCapabilities: [{
  'browserName': 'firefox'
}, {
  'browserName': 'chrome'
}]
```

Comment: Yes. I know I can change my config.js file with these options, but I want to know if there is a way to run multiple browsers via the command line args.